# Perl Repetition after for loop and switch

Tags: perl, switch-statement, string-comparison, repeat

I  have 2 arrays (array1, array2) and I'm tryin to identify strings in common in both and make a substitution, then print out the content of array1.

Element in array2 replaces some elements in array1. In particular if there's :

```
array1 = 1.txt
```

and

```
array 2 = 1.txt 0.5
```

array1 will be :

```
array1 = 1.txt 0.5
```

I've tried to build up this code but it prints out all the elements twice.
Is there a way to avoid this problem? 
I know that there's a module in perl called "switch"... Maybe is this the solution? I don't know how it works.

```
@array1 = qw(76
    38
    0.13213855661882
    0.264277113237639
    1.txt
    ####
    20
    10
    -0.01235
    -0.0247000000000001
    10.txt
    ####
    20
    10
    -0.01235
    -0.0247000000000001
    2.txt
    ####
    46
    14
    0.117232213438735
    0.385191558441558
    10003.txt
    ####);
    @array2 = ("1.txt 0.5", "2.txt 1");

for ($i = 0 ; $i < @array1; $i++){
for ($k =0; $k < @array2; $k++){
    if (grep /$array1[$i]/, $array2[$k]){
        $array1[$i] =~ s/$array1[$i]/$array2[$k]/;
        print $array1[$i]."\n";
    }
    else {print "RIS ".$array1[$i]."\n";}
}
}
```

Result:

```
RIS 76
RIS 76
RIS 38
RIS 38
RIS 0.13213855661882
RIS 0.13213855661882
RIS 0.264277113237639
RIS 0.264277113237639
**1.txt 0.5**
RIS 1.txt 0.5
RIS ####
RIS ####
RIS 20
RIS 20
RIS 10
RIS 10
RIS -0.01235
RIS -0.01235
RIS -0.0247000000000001
RIS -0.0247000000000001
RIS 10.txt
RIS 10.txt
```

Result expected:

```
RIS 76
    RIS 38
    RIS 0.13213855661882
    RIS 0.264277113237639
    **1.txt 0.5**
    RIS 1.txt 0.5
    RIS ####
    RIS 20
    RIS 10
    RIS -0.01235
    RIS -0.0247000000000001
    RIS 10.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you're doing your print within the @array2 loop. Try this instead:

```
for ($i = 0 ; $i < @array1; $i++){
  for ($k =0; $k < @array2; $k++){
    if (grep /$array1[$i]/, $array2[$k]){
        $array1[$i] =~ s/$array1[$i]/$array2[$k]/;
    }
  }
  print $array1[$i]."\n";
}
```

If you want to be able to see if there was a change, try something like this:

```
for ($i = 0 ; $i < @array1; $i++){
  for ($k =0; $k < @array2; $k++){
    if (grep /$array1[$i]/, $array2[$k]){
        $array1[$i] =~ s/$array1[$i]/$array2[$k]/;
        $value = $array1[$i];
    }
    else { $value = "RIS ".$array1[$i]."\n"; }
  }
  print "$value\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your elements get printed twice because you're using a for loop to test for inclusion in the second array instead of some other method.

I suggest converting your second array into a hash of key value pairs.  Then it is a simple hash inclusion test to see if a key needs to be replaced.

Something like the following would work for you.  Please note the usage of `use strict;` and `use warnings;`.  They should be used in EVERY script.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw(say);

my @array1 = do {
    no warnings 'qw';
    qw(
        76 38 0.13213855661882  0.264277113237639   1.txt     ####
        20 10 -0.01235          -0.0247000000000001 10.txt    ####
        20 10 -0.01235          -0.0247000000000001 2.txt     ####
        46 14 0.117232213438735 0.385191558441558   10003.txt ####
    )
};

my @array2 = ( "1.txt 0.5", "2.txt 1" );
my %trans = map {my ($key) = split ' '; ($key => $_)} @array2;

for my $element (@array1) {
    say $trans{$element} // "RIS $element";
}
```

Outputs:

```
RIS 76
RIS 38
RIS 0.13213855661882
RIS 0.264277113237639
1.txt 0.5
RIS ####
RIS 20
RIS 10
RIS -0.01235
RIS -0.0247000000000001
RIS 10.txt
RIS ####
RIS 20
RIS 10
RIS -0.01235
RIS -0.0247000000000001
2.txt 1
RIS ####
RIS 46
RIS 14
RIS 0.117232213438735
RIS 0.385191558441558
RIS 10003.txt
RIS ####
```